# How large/heavy is a Chocobo Egg?

Tags: final-fantasy

Pretty much exactly as above: For reasons related to tabletop gaming and spaceship cargo bookkeeping (Yes, really. I am a nerd.) I kind of need to know how heavy (roughly speaking) a Chocobo egg would be. The actual size would be helpful too (I know there's a way of measuring stuff using perspective, but the exact mechanics involved make my brain ooze a little bit).

One thought I had was to find a picture of a Chocobo egg, and one of an ostrich egg, then size it up and use the ostrich egg's weight to calculate the weight of a Chocobo egg, but... Well, that's kind of beyond my current level of education and mental capabilities.

Help me stack exchange. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A chocobo egg is about 36 cm long and weighs about 20 kg.

I couldn't find any good sources on how much a chocobo weighs. It probably doesn't matter anyway, because [bird to egg weight ratios vary wildly across species](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1096-3642.1927.tb02180.x#:%7E:text=The%20body%E2%80%90weights%20range%20from,decreases%20from%2012.2%20per%20cent.).

I did, however, find one clear [screenshot of a chocobo egg from *Type-0*](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobo_breeding_(Type-0)?file=Chocobo-egg-Type-0.jpg) and compared the egg against other objects in the shot.

[image: Screenshot of a chocobo egg from Final Fantasy Type-0.]

The egg itself is approximately 180 pixels tall along its major axis.

The chocobo chick is 115 pixels tall. As chocobo chicks are [about 17 cm tall](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobo_chick#Final_Fantasy_VIII), this works out to approximately 0.15 cm/pixel.

The character on the left stands 400 pixels at the waist. It's not clear which *Type-0* protagonist he is, which puts his height anywhere [between 168 and 187 cm](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Type-0_characters). If his waist is about half his height, that works out to between 0.21 and 0.23 cm/pixel.

The chick looks to be slightly behind the egg and the character slightly in front, so let's make it an even 0.20 cm/pixel.

### This makes our chocobo egg 36 cm tall.

To get a sense of the weight, let's compare this to other bird eggs.

Ostrich eggs [average 15 cm long and weigh 1.35 kg](https://www.britannica.com/animal/ostrich). We should expect the mass to be roughly proportional to the cube of its length, which works out to 0.4 g/cm^3.

Large chicken eggs [weigh at least 56.7 g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_egg_sizes#United_States) and are about 5 cm long (source: my kitchen), or 0.45 g/cm^3.

(As a quick math check, this is about half the density of water. But we've essentially doubled the volume of the egg by treating the length as the side of a cube instead of the diameter of a sphere. That makes eggs about as dense as water, which makes sense.)

### This makes our chocobo egg weigh 20 kg.

Comment: Perfect! And a nice round number to make storing then by the ton easier to boot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to be of service! If I've answered your question, you can click on the check mark to the left to accept it (although we usually recommend waiting at least 24 hours to see if other answers crop up).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would imagine scaling to be unnecessary I always pictured the average chocobo as around the size of an ostrich albeit somewhat heavier due to physical differences that allow people to ride them without harming them.

Lacking any canon source I would probably use the ostrich egg numbers especially since eggs are not uniform